# Power BI M language - transform tag list into multiple rows

Tags: powerquery, m

Is it possible using query GUI or using M to create multiple output/target records based on analyzing source field? For example, if I have a source field as a list of tags separated by semicolons and have each tag as a single record in the target?

E.g. in the source:

```
"RecordX",  "Tag1; Tag2; Tag3; Tag4"
"RecordY",  "Tag2; Tag3; Tag5; Tag6"
```

In the target as separate records/lines:

```
"RecordX", "Tag1"
"RecordX", "Tag2"
"RecordX", "Tag3"
"RecordX", "Tag4"
"RecordY", "Tag2"
"RecordY", "Tag3"
"RecordY", "Tag5"
"RecordY", "Tag6"
```

Somebody in a similar case suggested the "unpivot" function. is it the solution for this?
I need at least to understand terminology to look for the right functions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your source data is like a JSON object or something?

Perhaps it looks like this:

```json
{
    "RecordX":  "Tag1; Tag2; Tag3; Tag4",
    "RecordY":  "Tag2; Tag3; Tag5; Tag6"
}
```

And if that is the case, then I suggest you check this answer: [Convert json List Record to Table value in PowerBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54966563/convert-json-list-record-to-table-value-in-powerbi).

@Alexis is right, it is the 'Split Column By Delimiter' in to Rows which will solve this for you. See more details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-a-column-of-text-power-query-5282d425-6dd0-46ca-95bf-8e0da9539662) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/split-columns-delimiter).

For simplicity, here's a reproducible example:

```
let
    Source =
        "
        {
            ""RecordX"":  ""Tag1; Tag2; Tag3; Tag4"",
            ""RecordY"":  ""Tag2; Tag3; Tag5; Tag6""
        }
        ",
    ToJSON = Json.Document(Source),
    ToTable = Record.ToTable(ToJSON),
    SplitByDelimiter =
        Table.ExpandListColumn(
            Table.TransformColumns(
                ToTable,
                {
                    {
                        "Value",
                        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("; ", QuoteStyle.Csv),
                        let
                            itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]
                        in
                            type {itemType}
                    }
                }
            ),
            "Value"
        )
in
    SplitByDelimiter
```

Which has the result:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| RecordX | Tag1 |
| RecordX | Tag2 |
| RecordX | Tag3 |
| RecordX | Tag4 |
| RecordY | Tag2 |
| RecordY | Tag3 |
| RecordY | Tag5 |
| RecordY | Tag6 |

Answer (score 2):

The Split Column > By Delimiter is perfect for this.

[image: GUI]

Be sure to choose Rows under the Advanced options or it will split into columns by default.

Comment: Perfect! many thanks. It worked. Before I was doing custom scripts for this, VBA, Python, etc.
BTW - what "Quote Character" is for? Does it mean that besides separator it can process quoted strings as well, like "tag1", "tag2", etc.?

Comment: The documentation is a bit sparse for that argument but, yes, it's related to what characters indicate the start of a quoted string.